# what is the good way of matching group by total to whole total

Tags: postgresql

I have the below problem. Seems to be a simple query, but I couldn't figure it out after spending so much time.

```
Table
-----
project
mission
craft
```

project can have many missions, for each mission, it can use multiple air crafts. I want to identify the crafts that was involved with all the missions.

For eg if there are 10 missions, mission 1 can use craft 1 and 2. If there is any craft that used for all the 10 missions (mission 1 -10), that should be output.

I wrote,

```
select craft,count(mission) from table group by craft
```

After this I don't know how can I match this value to the total missions. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this for single project you need filter number of craft's missions by total number of missions:

```
select c.id from (
   select c.id, count(mission_id) cnt
   from craft c inner join mission m on (m.id = c.mission_id)
   where m.project_id = <project_id> 
   group by c.id
) as c 
where c.cnt = (select count(*) from mission where project_id = <project_id>)
```

If you need this for all projects:

```
select c.project_id, c.id from (
   select m.project_id, c.id, count(mission_id) cnt
   from craft c inner join mission m on (m.id = c.mission_id) 
   group by m.project_id, c.id
) as c inner join (
   select project_id, count(*) cnt
   from mission
   group by project_id
) as m on (m.project_id = c.project_id)
where c.cnt = m.cnt
```

Comment: project , mission , craft are fields of craft table

Answer (score 0):

```
with mission as (
    select distinct mission
    from craft
), craft_missions as (
    select craft, count(*) as total_missions
    from
        craft c
        inner join
        mission m on m.mission = c.mission
    group by craft
)
select craft
from craft_missions
where total_missions = (select count(*) from mission)
```